# WriteFile returns 0 as the number of bytes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke

I want to be able to copy 4 GBs of data from a drive to a file and restore it. Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal extern static IntPtr CreateFile(
       String fileName,
       int dwDesiredAccess,
       FileShare dwShareMode,
       IntPtr securityAttrs_MustBeZero,
       FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
       int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
       IntPtr hTemplateFile_MustBeZero);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetVolumeInformationByHandleW(
        IntPtr hDisk,
        StringBuilder volumeNameBuffer,
        int volumeNameSize,
        ref uint volumeSerialNumber,
        ref uint maximumComponentLength,
        ref uint fileSystemFlags,
        StringBuilder fileSystemNameBuffer,
        int nFileSystemNameSize);

    // Used to read in a file
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadFile(
        IntPtr hFile,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
        ref uint lpNumberOfBytesRead,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool WriteFile(
        IntPtr hFile,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
        out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
        [In] ref NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);


    // Used to set the offset in file to start reading
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetFilePointerEx(
        IntPtr hFile,
        long liDistanceToMove,
        ref long lpNewFilePointer,
        uint dwMoveMethod);

    internal const int GENERIC_READ = unchecked((int)0x80000000);

    internal const int FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = unchecked((int)0x02000000);

    internal const int OPEN_EXISTING = unchecked((int)3);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr hDrive = CreateFile(
            string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}:", "G"),
            GENERIC_READ,
            FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (FileMode)OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        RunBackup(hDrive);

        RunRestore(hDrive);

        CloseHandle(hDrive);
    }

    private static void RunRestore(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // Set offset
        uint chunks = 100;
        uint bufferSize = 512 * chunks;
        long pt = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        SetFilePointerEx(
            handle,
            0,
            ref pt,
            0);

        long oneGB = 1073741824;
        var backupSize = oneGB * 4;
        var loops = backupSize / bufferSize;

        Console.WriteLine($"Expecting {loops:N0} loops.");
        var ol = new NativeOverlapped();
        uint written = 0;
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(@"D:\\fat.backup")))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                reader.Read(buffer);

                WriteFile(
                    handle,
                    buffer,
                    bufferSize,
                    out written,
                    ref ol);

                Console.Write($"\rLoop: {i:N0}");
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void RunBackup(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // Set offset
        uint chunks = 100;
        uint bufferSize = 512 * chunks;
        long pt = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        SetFilePointerEx(
            handle,
            0,
            ref pt,
            0);

        long oneGB = 1073741824;
        var backupSize = oneGB * 4;
        var loops = backupSize / bufferSize;

        Console.WriteLine($"Expecting {loops:N0} loops.");

        uint read = 0;
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"D:\\fat.backup")))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                ReadFile(
                    handle,
                    buffer,
                    bufferSize,
                    ref read,
                    IntPtr.Zero);

                writer.Write(buffer);
                writer.Flush();

                Console.Write($"\rLoop: {i:N0}");
            }

            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The backup function seems to be working as expected. However, in the restore part, when the program calls the `WriteFile`, the `written` variable is always 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/creating-and-opening-files and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb34a1d6-0942-47bd-8e2f-3489b88808c7/using-overlapped-io-in-net?forum=clr

Comment: Why does this require PInvoke in the first place? You should be able to use normal `FileStream` for `\\.\G:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same handle for both routines, and it was opened for read access.

If you open a file for read only, and then use the same handle to write, it's pretty obvious you're going to have problems.

#### Solution

In order to write to the disk use the `CreateFile` function like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal extern static IntPtr CreateFile(
    String fileName,
    FileAccess access,
    FileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr securityAttrs_MustBeZero,
    FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
    int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile_MustBeZero);

IntPtr handle = CreateFile(
    string.Format("\\\\.\\{0}:", driveLetter),
    (FileAccess)(0x40000000),
    (FileShare)0x00000001,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    0x00000080,
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: I commented out the first function then ran it. And I passed the `FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write`. I'm guessing it's the GENERIC_READ value that's causing the problem. What's the value that I need to pass then?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori: You'll need to do some work on your own. Look at the reference for the function you use to open the file and pass the appropriate value for write access (if you want to write).

Comment: I edited your answer and added the solution.